# Enter/Join A Line

Tags: meaning, usage, word-difference

Suppose the AE / BE terminology difference over line and queue is ignored.

According to native speakers ( and google searches), the following:

> He ***joined*** the lunch line.

is standard English.  But then, I found this:

> He ***entered*** the lunch line.

Google searches suggest that "*enter* a line" is less common than "*join* a line".  So, is "enter a line" formal English?

Comment: It depends on the line's location.  On one side of the Atlantic you might *queue up,* on the other side you might *get in line.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I was a child fifty-ump years ago and actually stood in line to get my school lunch, the expression was invariably ***get*** in the lunch line.

*Join* a line is an acceptable variant, which avoids the informality of *get*. (But I doubt that *get* will be unacceptable in any register if what you're speaking of is lunch lines.)

I have never encountered *enter* a line in this sense, and a quick Google suggests that it is used primarily of military units taking an assigned place in a line of battle, or of *entering*—keyboarding—a line of text into a field. It is odd in the context of a queue: it suggests ‘breaking’ into the line, not taking a place at the end of it.

Stick with *get*, or *join* if *get* makes you uncomfortable.